# In Mathematica, how can I find patterns that include rules and lists?

Tags: design-patterns, wolfram-mathematica

Example:

```
test = {"a" -> {{1}, 12}, "b" -> {13}}
```

I'd like to find all expressions in the list with this pattern:

```
_ -> {_,_}
```

The first element, "a" -> {{1}, 12}, is represented by this pattern.

However, none of these expressions work:

```
Cases[test,_->{_,_}], Cases[test,_->_], Cases[test,Rule[_,_]], etc.
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is `HoldPattern`:

```
In[1]:= test = {"a" -> {{1}, 12}, "b" -> {13}};

In[2]:= Cases[test, HoldPattern[_ -> {_, _}]] // InputForm
Out[2]= {"a" -> {{1}, 12}}
```

**EDIT:** This also works with named pattern variables.

```
In[3]:= Cases[test, HoldPattern[_ -> {x_, _}] :> x]
Out[3]= {{1}}
```

Comment: Excellent. This seems to be what I'm looking for. Is it possible to have named pattern variables, e.g. 
_->{_,_x} /; x<10
while using HoldPattern?